# How does streaming audio work on the web?

Tags: audio, web, browser, audio-streaming

I realize this is a very broad question. I'm interested in a high-level overview of the whole process of how the audio data gets from a server hosting an audio file, to my sound card.

I would imagine that there are at least three interesting interface points in the process:

1. How is the audio data transferred **from the server to the client**?
2. Once the audio data has reached the client, **what web APIs does client code use to instruct the browser to play it**?
3. In the implementation of these web APIs, what **operating system APIs** does the browser use to actually play the audio? (I'm primarily interested in Windows and Linux).

I realize that there are probably several alternatives at each point. I'm looking for a high-level overview of the most commonly used technologies, preferrably with links to more resources for each.

Comment: i literally googled your title and tons of answers came up

Comment: @redFIVE, for a laugh, I did it too; 'About 85,700,000 results'.

Comment: What's wrong with him asking a question that has other results on google? He gives additional clarification around what particular things he is interested in. Having a consildated answer that covers each of his questions could be valuable to others.

Answer (score 1):

```
(How is the audio data transferred from the server to the client ?)
```

- one strategy : Web Sockets - the server and browser open up this two way channel which can transmit a series of binary typed arrays to be consumed by javascript on the browser - downside is the browser must context switch away from what its doing (rendering audio) to service messages received from the server - this may cause glitches in the audio rendering if you do not use Web Worker(s) on the browser side

.

```
(what web APIs does client code use to instruct the browser to play it?)
```

- Web Audio API - works great if you offload to a Web Worker the Web Socket chatter

.

```
In the implementation of these web APIs, what operating system APIs does the browser use to actually play the audio? (I'm primarily interested in Windows and Linux)
```

- beauty is, you can remain oblivious to this question as it has no bearings on the task at hand unless I am missing some agenda in your question

This is only my perspective (I've written a system which implements above approach), however I too am curious as to how others ... say SoundCloud ... implements its streaming audio, especially the single threaded browser issue ???